# Web Deploy Deployment package Installment Error "ERROR_FILE_IN_USE"

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, webdeploy

I made a deployment package of my web API with Microsoft Web Deploy, it contains a deploy.cmd file, a setParameters.xml file and a zip file in the folder. According to the Microsoft website, I can install the app to an iis website through the command prompt by executing the deploy.cmd file.
However, when I execute the cmd with the command, projectName.deploy.cmd /y, it throws an error that says

> Web Deploy cannot modify the file projectName.zip because it it locked by an external process.

I am trying to update to iis, but most of the articles I have read are in relation to installing on azure.

I have tried turning off the application pool when installing, but the error still persists. I have also tried adding

> '<'EnableMSDeployAppOffline'>'true'<'/EnableMSDeployAppOffline'>'

to the deploy profile in the publish profiles of my web api project. What might be locking the zip file in the deployment package?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, installing to the root of the website seems to be the thing that throws the error, making a sub folder in the website when making the publish profile in the visual studio resolves this problem quite well.